# How to track Global variable in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I want to track global variable from a service that I use in **multiple** components. I use the angular material 2 for my app.

What is the best way to do that?
Any example that I can do that is gonna help. thanx all for your help

I have this code and is not work, The theme is not toggling.

I have errors.

Failed to compile.

```
C:/Users/Developer/Documents/GitHub/STAGING/Test-/src/app/admin/pages/products/admin-add-new-product/admin-add-new-product.component.ts (20,3): Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'Boolean'.
  Types of property 'valueOf' are incompatible.
    Type '() => Object' is not assignable to type '() => boolean'.
      Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

### This is the mediator.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class MediatorService {

public isDarkTheme: Observable<any>;


  /**
   * Returns the selected theme
   */
  getTheme () {
    return this.isDarkTheme;
  }

  /**
   * Set the selected theme
   */
  setTheme (b) {
    this.isDarkTheme = b;
    console.log(this.isDarkTheme);
  }
```

}

### adminAddNewProduct.componet.ts

```
export class AdminAddNewProductComponent implements OnInit {

   isDarkTheme:  Boolean = this.mediator.getTheme();

}
```

#### And this component toggle the theme variable to true or false

### navbar.component.ts

```
/**
   * Set the selected theme
   */
  toggleTheme() {
    // this.isDarkTheme = this.isDarkTheme = true ? false : true;
    // console.log(this.isDarkTheme);
    this.mediator.setTheme(this.isDarkTheme);
  }
```

Comment: The problem is that you are treating the observable like a boolean value and that's exactly the error message you are receiving. I would expect that an editor/IDE which supports angular/TS would show you an error before even compiling.  Have a look at for e.g this tutorial : http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/ . It shows how to use an observable/subject (It targets angular 2, but this should not be a problem)

Comment: Thnx for your help